# How to send foreach data from controller to view ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Controller

```
public ActionResult SurveyDetails(int? id)      
{
    foreach (Question q in listQuestion)
    {
        List<QuestionAnswer> listQuestionAnswer = db.Question_answers.Where(p => p.QuestionId == q.Id).ToList();
        q.QuestionAnswers = listQuestionAnswer;
        ViewBag.Answer = listQuestionAnswer;
    };  
}
```

View

```
@foreach (var a in ViewBag.Answer)
{
    @a.Answer
}
```

The code just takes and displays the first item, how to show them all? Please help me

Comment: Why you need to use viewBag if you are already assigning answers to `q` which I belived is being passed to the view as model.

Comment: dont pass data from viewbag sent it from json to your view page than all data will show.